# Ассемблерный листинг машинного кода библиотеки под андроид

Tags: android, ассемблер

Андроид SDK & NDK установлены на Ubuntu. Есть ли в поставке стандартные средства?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть. Это arm-eabi-objdump.

```
$ .../android-ndk/build/prebuilt/linux-x86/arm-eabi-4.4.0/bin/arm-eabi-objdump -d файл
```